# does findByIdAndUpdate overwrites data not modified?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using findByIdAndUpdate to updated modified form fields.

does it overwrite all the fields in the document which are not even modified in the form?

Comment: Depends on the usage, do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Mongoose's docs:

> Issues a mongodb findAndModify update command by a document's `_id` field. `findByIdAndUpdate(id, ...)` is equivalent to `findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, ...)`.

> Finds a matching document, updates it according to the `update` arg, passing any `options`, and returns the found document (if any) to the callback. The query executes if `callback` is passed.

In short, it only overwrites **the selected document's attributes according to the object that you have sent to your `findByIdAndUpdate` method**. If the object that you have sent does not modify an attribute, then that attribute will be left as is.

Further reading: [Mongoose's docs about the topic](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html).